# jar -creation of log file in relative path using log4j

Tags: jar, log4j

Log file is created if an absolute path is provided in the log4j.properties in a runnable jar created using eclipse. However, if relative file path is given , file is not created

log4j.appender.appLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appLogger.File=.//logs//MyApp.log

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this in your log4j.properties.

log4j.appender.appLogger.File=/logs/MyApp.log

***For example:***

In Ubuntu(Linux).
`/home/bizruntime/Desktop/logs/MyApp.log`

In Windows.
`C:\\Desktop\logs\MyApp.log`

If i have my log file in some folder of Desktop i need to specific the exact path.